# Vectorized "and" for pandas columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vectorization

With a data like this one

```
import pandas as pd
tcd = pd.DataFrame({
 'a': {'p_1': 1, 'p_2': 1, 'p_3': 0, 'p_4': 0}, 
 'b': {'p_1': 0, 'p_2': 1, 'p_3': 1, 'p_4': 1}, 
 'c': {'p_1': 0, 'p_2': 0, 'p_3': 1, 'p_4': 0}})
tcd
#      a  b  c
# p_1  1  0  0
# p_2  1  1  0
# p_3  0  1  1
# p_4  0  1  0
```

(but with 40e3 columns)

I look for a vectorized way to put the boolean **and** in a result Series:

```
a & b = ab -> 1 or True    a & c = ac -> 0 or False
1   0   0                  1   0   0
1   1   0                  1   0   0
0   1   1                  0   1   0
0   1   0                  0   0   0
```

For now I only get an ugly solution with a for loop::

```
res = pd.Series(index=['a&a', 'a&b', 'a&c'])
for i in range(3):
  res[i] = (tcd.iloc[:, 0] & tcd.iloc[:, i]).any()

res 
aa    1
ab    1
ac    0
```

with the B.M. answer I get this

```
def get_shared_p(tcd, i):
    res = (tcd.iloc[:, i][:, None] & tcd).any()
    res.index += '&_{}'.format(i)
    return res

res = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(cols), index=range(cols))
for col_i in range(cols):
    res.iloc[:, col_i] = list(get_shared_p(tcd, col_i))

print res
#        0     1      2
# 0   True  True  False
# 1   True  True   True
# 2  False  True   True
```

We can probably avoid this new *for* loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[:,None]` to align data and force broadcasting :

```
In[1] : res=(tcd.a[:,None] & tcd).any(); res.index+='&a'; res

Out[1]:
a&a     True
b&a     True
c&a    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: really great @b-m ! BTW can we use the same method to get the cross matrix with &a, &b, &c or with  &_0, &_1, &2

Comment: IIUC,`res=(tcd.T.p_1[:,None] & tcd.T).any();res.index+='&p_1';res` ?

Comment: I don' t think it's so simple in upper dimensions.  

 A solution : `u=tcd.values.T;pd.DataFrame((u[:,None] & u).any(2),tcd.columns,tcd.columns)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and [numpy's broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Say you define `x` and `y` as the first column, and entire matrix, respectively:

```
import numpy as np

x = tcd.as_matrix()
y = tcd.a.values.reshape((len(tcd), 1))
```

now, using broadcasting, find the logical and of `x` and `y`, and place it in `and_`:

```
and_ = np.logical_and(x, y)
```

Finally, find if any of the rows in any of the columns is true:

```
>>> np.sum(and_) > 0
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem by that way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

tcd = pd.DataFrame({
 'a': {'p_1': 1, 'p_2': 1, 'p_3': 0, 'p_4': 0},
 'b': {'p_1': 0, 'p_2': 1, 'p_3': 1, 'p_4': 1},
 'c': {'p_1': 0, 'p_2': 0, 'p_3': 1, 'p_4': 0}})

for c in combinations(tcd.columns, 2):
    tcd[c[0]+c[1]] = np.logical_and(tcd[c[0]], tcd[c[1]])

print(cd)
```

With output:

```
     a  b  c     ab     ac     bc
p_1  1  0  0  False  False  False
p_2  1  1  0   True  False  False
p_3  0  1  1  False  False   True
p_4  0  1  0  False  False  False
```

Comment: I have to say, this seems like it will be really slow.